# Target SDK 28 and Bluetooth connectivity issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an app that was working perfectly across all Android devices until I changed the target SDK to 28. After changing the SDK to 28 on Android 9 devices the Bluetooth cannot get connected to Bluetooth devices and the Activity trying to use the Bluetooth is restarted. I do not have the logcat output because this happens on the user phone and unfortunately I do not have any phone with Android 9. But when I change the target SDK to 26 then 
the connection to the Bluetooth device (in my case a portable printer) was done successfully on Android 9. Pay attention that this problem happens on Android 9 but not 8 nor 4. I have Android 8 and 4 at hand but not 9. AS there is only complaint from users whom Android version is 9 I can conclud that there is a bug in Android 9. I have posted my codes below. Just pay attention that changing target SDK to 26 solved the problem.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ilia.anrdAcunt.ui"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26//***28 restarts the Bluetooth activity
       //If I change the taget SDK to 28 then there is an error
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        demo_flavor {
            minSdkVersion 15
            applicationId 'ilia.anrdAcunt.uidemo'
            targetSdkVersion 26//***28 restarts the Bluetooth activity
        }
        mainver_flavor {
            minSdkVersion 15
            applicationId 'ilia.anrdAcunt.ui'
            targetSdkVersion 26//***28 restarts the Bluetooth activity
        }
        kasabeh_flavor {
            minSdkVersion 15
            applicationId 'ilia.anrdAcunt.ui'
            targetSdkVersion 26//***28 restarts the Bluetooth activity
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':AnrdLib')
    ///compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/itextg-5.5.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs/sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/scpkix-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/WoosimLib231.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-net-3.6.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/adad-2.8.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
}
```

The manifest file common to all flavors:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="1"
    package="ilia.anrdAcunt.ui">

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
...
```

And the permissions in the Manifest.xml file (Flavor specific manifest):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ilia.anrdAcunt.ui"
    android:versionCode="130"
    android:versionName="8.55">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
...
```

And the code for connecting, writing and reading to/from the Bluetooth device:

```
package ilia.anrdAcunt.woosim.prnLib;

import ilia.anrdAcunt.ui.R;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * This class does all the work for setting up and managing Bluetooth connections with printers.
 * It has a thread for connecting with a printer, and a thread for performing data transmissions when connected.
 */
public class BluetoothPrintService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothPrintService";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID SPP_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private int mState;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device


    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new Bluetooth session.
     * @param context  The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler  A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothPrintService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the connection
     * @param state  An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state. 
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the print service. Called by the Activity onResume() 
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel(); 
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel(); 
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice to connect
     * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel(); 
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel(); 
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     * @param socket  The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device  The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device, final String socketType) {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel(); 
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel(); 
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(WoosimPrnMng.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(WoosimPrnMng.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "stop");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;

        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        // When the application is destroyed, just return 
        if (mState == STATE_NONE) return;

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(WoosimPrnMng.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(WoosimPrnMng.TOAST, R.string.wConnect_fail);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothPrintService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // When the application is destroyed, just return 
        if (mState == STATE_NONE) return;

        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(WoosimPrnMng.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(WoosimPrnMng.TOAST, R.string.wConnect_lost);
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothPrintService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private String mSocketType;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SPP_UUID);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
            setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType + " socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "Connection Failed", e);
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothPrintService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // buffer can be over-written by next input stream data, so it should be copied
                    byte[] rcvData = new byte[bytes];
                    rcvData = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, bytes);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(WoosimPrnMng.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, rcvData).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection Lost", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         * @param buffer  The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmInStream.close();
                mmOutStream.close();
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I think the problem is just risen because of additional security that is added to Android 9. I hope one of those smart engineers who add the security (or better who added the limitations) to Android 9 post the solution.

Comment: Can this have anything to do with clearTextTraffic stuff that was added in android 9? Just a guess. Hope I'm not bothering you.

Comment: Thank you for the point that was also my guess. So I have added both android:targetSandboxVersion="1" and android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to the manifest but no luck. Actually these lines solved the problem of http communication but had no effect on Bluetooth. I also changed the question to reflect your point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tried that with no lock.  I have changed the question to reflect this.